# Find the value of the expression $\left (2 + 5 \right ) + \left (2^{2}+5^{2} \right ) + \left (2^{3}+5^{3} \right ) + \left (2^{4}+5^{4} \right )$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How to effectively solve this expression?

> $$\left (2 + 5 \right ) + \left (2^{2}+5^{2}  \right ) + \left (2^{3}+5^{3}  \right ) + \left (2^{4}+5^{4}  \right )$$

---

Inefficient method:

> $$\left (7 \right ) + \left (29  \right ) + \left (133  \right ) + \left (641  \right ) = 810$$

Comment: **Hint:** Regroup the terms, and use geometric series.

Comment: @Lucian Thank you Lucian!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's
$$(2+2^2+2^3+2^4)+(5+5^2+5^3+5^4) = (1+2+ \dots+2^4)+(1+5+ \dots +5^4)-2 =$$
$$=(2^5-1)+ (5^5-1)/4 -2 = 31 + 781 - 2 = 810$$

Comment: How awful that I couldn't see this decision( Thank you friend. It is a signal that I should go to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Use the geometric sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}m^k=\frac{m^{n+1}-1}{m-1}-1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left (2 + 5 \right ) + \left (2^{2}+5^{2}  \right ) + \left (2^{3}+5^{3}  \right ) + \left (2^{4}+5^{4}  \right ) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^4 2^i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^4 5^i\right) = \frac{2-2^5}{1-2} + \frac{5-5^5}{1-5} = 30 + 5(5^4-1)/4 = 30+5\times 624/4=30+780=810$$